Is indistinguishability required for the stability of matter?
Classically, it is well-known that a charge-neutral system of electrons and nuclei is thermodynamically unstable. In simplistic terms, nothing in classical mechanics prevents electrons from binding arbitrarily tightly to nuclei. The total energy of the system can become arbitrarily large and negative, and we conclude that the system is not stable. Quantum mechanics must be invoked in some form to explain the stability of matter.
I am aware of (but not intimate with) some of the proofs of the stability of matter, by Dyson & Lenard and by Lieb and co-workers. The fact that electrons are fermions appears to be necessary; bosonic electrons are demonstrated not to be stable. The Exclusion Principle seems like a crucial element of the stability of matter to prevent the "collapse" that occurs classically. These proofs are concerned with the ground state of matter.
At sufficiently high temperatures, however, I would expect the effects of spin statistics to become irrelevant. For all practical purposes, there is a point where it is "good enough" to regard electrons as being distinguishable. This leads to my question: Can a charge-neutral system of distinguishable electrons and nuclei be stable?
Stated another way, if our starting point is the unstable classical system, can stability be achieved only by invoking the probabilistic nature of electrons, or must their indistinguishability (and the Exclusion Principle) eventually come in?

By distinguishable you mean not including the $1/N!$ in $Z$? By the way, distinguishability has nothing to do with quantum mechanics (this is a lie told by many textbook for some reason...) and has everything to do with what information is accessible to us and how we chose to measure our system, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0206

That's an angle I was not thinking about; I could have framed the question more narrowly. I mean "distinguishability" in the sense of the exchange (anti)symmetry of wave functions. That is a different question than what Frenkel's article is addressing (but it was a very interesting read!).

In quantum mechanics, an electron doesn't have a definite position or momentum. It has a wave function from which the probability of finding it at a particular position or momentum can be calculated. An electron bound to a proton will probably be very near the proton.
The Uncertainty Principle says that if the uncertainty of an electron's position is reduced by confining near a proton, then the uncertainty in its momentum increases. An electron that may have a high momentum isn't likely to stay near a proton very long.
There is a size where these two opposing uncertainties balance. This determines the size of atoms.
